# Event showing partial data in google analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am sending event data from my website to Google Analytics however when try to view the data sent...it does not show me all the data....What is the exact procedure to see the same.
Here is what I've done so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-76384817-1', 'none');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then I send the data like this

```
ga('send', 'event', pathName, val.id); });
```

And I go to in events under Behaviour  in GA account but I can not see all the data.
How to see the recent or datewise data under events?

Comment: Install GA Debugger for Chrome to see if your event data is being sent. Also check if you are not filtering your own hits via an IP filter. If it's show some of the data and not some, then there must be something else wrong.

Comment: While debugging GA , I can see in Tag assistant showing me a warning as "Code found outside of <head> tag"....I have the code in an external file in a function which I execute on all pages on a click...What should I be doing now?

Comment: @nyuen I am trying it on local host